# Video upload error when choosing from library

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a video from my library to Firebase storage in my application, but it seems to be resulting in an error. This does not happen if the video has been captured using UIImagePicker, it only happens when the user pickes an already taken video. I am using XCode `11.0 beta (11M336w)` and iOS 13 `beta 3`.

My ImagePicker class:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import CropViewController

public protocol ImagePickerDelegate: class {
    func didSelect(image: UIImage?)
    func didSelect(fileUrl: URL)
}

open class ImagePicker: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, CropViewControllerDelegate {

    private let pickerController: UIImagePickerController
    private weak var presentationController: UIViewController?
    private weak var delegate: ImagePickerDelegate?

    private var editing = false
    private var croppingStyle: CropViewCroppingStyle!

    public init(presentationController: UIViewController, delegate: ImagePickerDelegate, editing: Bool, croppingStyle: CropViewCroppingStyle, mediaTypes: [String]?) {
        self.pickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        super.init()

        self.presentationController = presentationController
        self.delegate = delegate

        self.pickerController.delegate = self
        self.editing = editing
        self.croppingStyle = croppingStyle

        if let mediaTypes = mediaTypes {
            self.pickerController.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
        } else if let mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .camera) {
            self.pickerController.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
        }
        self.pickerController.sourceType = .camera
        self.pickerController.showsCameraControls = true
        self.pickerController.videoQuality = .typeHigh

        self.pickerController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = nil
        self.pickerController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(nil, for: .normal)
        self.pickerController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(nil, for: .highlighted)
    }

    private func action(for type: UIImagePickerController.SourceType, title: String) -> UIAlertAction? {
        guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(type) else {
            return nil
        }

        return UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default) { [unowned self] _ in
            self.pickerController.sourceType = type
            self.presentationController?.present(self.pickerController, animated: true)
        }
    }

    public func present(from sourceView: UIView) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        if let action = self.action(for: .camera, title: "Take photo or video") {
            alertController.addAction(action)
        }
        if let action = self.action(for: .photoLibrary, title: "Choose from library") {
            alertController.addAction(action)
        }

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        cancel.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
        alertController.addAction(cancel)

        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
            alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sourceView.bounds
            alertController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = [.down, .up]
        }

        self.presentationController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }

    private func pickerController(_ controller: UIImagePickerController, didSelect image: UIImage?) {
        self.delegate?.didSelect(image: image)
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func pickerController(_ controller: UIImagePickerController, didSelectVideo videoUrl: URL) {
        self.delegate?.didSelect(fileUrl: videoUrl)
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.pickerController(picker, didSelect: nil)
    }

    var picker: UIImagePickerController!
    public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        if let videoUrl = info[.mediaURL] as? URL {
            self.pickerController(picker, didSelectVideo: videoUrl)
            return
        }

        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            if editing {
                let cropViewController = CropViewController(croppingStyle: croppingStyle, image: image)
                cropViewController.delegate = self
                self.picker = picker
                self.presentationController?.present(cropViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.pickerController(picker, didSelect: image)
            }
        } else {
            self.pickerController(picker, didSelect: nil)
        }
    }

    public func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: CropViewController, didCropToImage image: UIImage, withRect cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int) {
        self.pickerController(picker, didSelect: image)
    }
}
```

I present the viewcontroller with the following function inside my UITableView class (I just call this function when a button has been pressed):

```
func choose() {
    let imagePicker = ImagePicker(presentationController: self, delegate: self, editing: false, croppingStyle: .default, mediaTypes: nil)
    imagePicker.present(from: view)
}
```

Then in the imagepicker delegate I use this code:

```
func didSelect(image: UIImage?) {
    //
}

func didSelect(fileUrl: URL) {
    let uuid = NSUUID().uuidString
    let path = uuid + "." + fileUrl.pathExtension

    let uploadTask = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "message_videos/\(path)").putFile(from: fileUrl, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        print("success!")
    }
}
```

When executed, this results in the following console prints:

```
2019-07-05 23:41:31.967623+0200 APPLICATION_NAME[9491:1007368] Failed to issue sandbox extension for file file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/8B54AF9B-6618-4341-85DE-2EAC29198B17/tmp/trim.FEF41C1D-7D43-4E95-84A1-36AC99FEDE14.MOV, errno = 1
2019-07-05 23:41:31.982082+0200 APPLICATION_NAME[9491:1007368] Task <D08D778E-B5DD-4182-9FFE-69E892DA8EDE>.<1> finished with error [-1] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com/o/message_videos%2FBB2CB773-982B-4800-9398-B2F96ED91B6D.MOV?uploadType=resumable&name=message_videos%2FBB2CB773-982B-4800-9398-B2F96ED91B6D.MOV&upload_id=AEnB2UqDOZNKSdC1TCdzQB4OV3ZS74snMqsQ4tPZRZy3iYUjO47TrpnMOrDz6HUq-_KFRAdfqhahEJsefrXe_N8T-jF8MS05cA&upload_protocol=resumable, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com/o/message_videos%2FBB2CB773-982B-4800-9398-B2F96ED91B6D.MOV?uploadType=resumable&name=message_videos%2FBB2CB773-982B-4800-9398-B2F96ED91B6D.MOV&upload_id=AEnB2UqDOZNKSdC1TCdzQB4OV3ZS74snMqsQ4tPZRZy3iYUjO47TrpnMOrDz6HUq-_KFRAdfqhahEJsefrXe_N8T-jF8MS05cA&upload_protocol=resumable, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "BackgroundUploadTask <D08D778E-B5DD-4182-9FFE-69E892DA8EDE>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundUploadTask <D08D778E-B5DD-4182-9FFE-69E892DA8EDE>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error}
Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={bucket=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundUploadTask <D08D778E-B5DD-4182-9FFE-69E892DA8EDE>.<1>, object=message_videos/BB2CB773-982B-4800-9398-B2F96ED91B6D.MOV, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "BackgroundUploadTask <D08D778E-B5DD-4182-9FFE-69E892DA8EDE>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response., ResponseErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomain, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com/o/message_videos%2FBB2CB773-982B-4800-9398-B2F96ED91B6D.MOV?uploadType=resumable&name=message_videos%2FBB2CB773-982B-4800-9398-B2F96ED91B6D.MOV&upload_id=AEnB2UqDOZNKSdC1TCdzQB4OV3ZS74snMqsQ4tPZRZy3iYUjO47TrpnMOrDz6HUq-_KFRAdfqhahEJsefrXe_N8T-jF8MS05cA&upload_protocol=resumable, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com/o/message_videos%2FBB2CB773-982B-4800-9398-B2F96ED91B6D.MOV?uploadType=resumable&name=message_videos%2FBB2CB773-982B-4800-9398-B2F96ED91B6D.MOV&upload_id=AEnB2UqDOZNKSdC1TCdzQB4OV3ZS74snMqsQ4tPZRZy3iYUjO47TrpnMOrDz6HUq-_KFRAdfqhahEJsefrXe_N8T-jF8MS05cA&upload_protocol=resumable, ResponseErrorCode=-1}
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: That's a whole lot of code for us to digest and you are using beta software which will inherently have bugs; you should use released products. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please update your question with less code and put a breakpoint in your code and step through it until it crashes. Indicate what line is crashing.

Comment: @Devxln Did you ever find a solution to this? I think I have the same problem.

Comment: @TaylorM I did not unfortunately, but I did not include video uploads anymore, I am open to any solutions

Comment: Same issue for me...still with latest release iOS13

Answer (score 3):

So I was able to solve this issue in my app by converting the video to `Data` and uploading that using the `putData` function from Firebase Storage API.

I'm not exactly sure why this change was necessary with iOS 13, but I hope this helps.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    //ensure user picked a video and you have the URL
    guard let mediaType = info[.mediaType] as? String, mediaType == "public.movie", let movieURL = info[.mediaURL] as? URL else {
        dismiss(animated: true)
        return
    }

    uploadVideo(url: movieURL)

    //continue code your here...
}

private func uploadVideo(url: URL) {
    do {
        //convert video to Data
        let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: movieURL)

        //build storage "path"
        let uniqueID = UUID().uuidString
        let path = "message_videos/" + uniqueID
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(path)

        //use metadata to specify it's a video            
        let uploadMetadata = StorageMetadata()
        uploadMetadata.contentType = "video/quicktime"

        //upload via putData
        let uploadTask = storageRef.putData(videoData, metadata: uploadMetadata) { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                //handle upload error
            } else {
                //successful upload
            }
        } catch {
            //handle video -> Data error
        }
    }
}
```